# React JS appending

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/lodivivaba/2/edit?html,js,output)

I want to append the obj on container everytime I click the buttons how can I do this ?

This is only replacing the container.

Also I want to keep those button eventListeners of button1,button2 in jquery.

**HTML**

```
<h1 class="h1">This is H1</h1>
<button class="button1">This is button1</button>
<button class="button2">This is button2</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**JSX**

```
    var obj = [
        {
            'name' : 'Denis Mcarthy',
            'id' : 5,
            'comment' : "fuck this shit",
            'me' : true,
            'pp' : 'https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/598730?v=3&s=88'
        },
        {
            'name' : 'John Cena',
            'id' : 8,
            'comment' : "This is Dope. Bring some Coke",
            'pp' : 'https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/96150?v=3&s=88'
        }               
    ];  
    var obj2 = [
        {
            'name' : 'Kendall Bitch',
            'id' : 5,
            'comment' : "What the Fuck",
            'me' : true,
            'pp' : 'https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/598730?v=3&s=88'
        },
        {
            'name' : 'Randy Orton',
            'id' : 8,
            'comment' : "Suck this bitch",
            'pp' : 'https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/96150?v=3&s=88'
        }               
    ];      
$('.button1').click(function(){
    renderTweet(obj); 
});
$('.button2').click(function(){
    renderTweet(obj2); 
});



        function renderTweet(obj){
        var TweetBox = React.createClass({
          render: function() {
            return ( 

        <div>
            {obj.map((row,i) =>     
                <div className="well clearfix">
                    <img src={row.pp} />
                    <div id={row.id}>
                        {row.name}
                        <br />
                        {row.comment}
                    </div>
                 </div>
            )}  
        </div>

            );
          }
        });


        ReactDOM.render(
          <TweetBox />,
          document.getElementById("container")
        );      
    }
```

Comment: append means, as i click the button it needs to add the same object again and again ??

Comment: yes add the same obj again and again

Comment: one more thing, why you want to use jquery, you can do this easily in React js ?

Comment: @MayankShukla im happy to use react as long as it does not render `button1` and `button2`  . those are to be directly written on html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't render to `document.getElementById("container")`, but to `document.getElementById("container").appendChild(document.createElement('div'))`

This will append an empty div to `#container` and returns that div to the render function for React to use

Comment: yes it does works, .....  but is there any other way out because its creating a un necessary div element ?

Comment: that's a price we all have to pay with JSX :) Is there a reason to not want a wrapper div?

Comment: i think ill pay the price for now

Answer (score 0):

Use another var `final` that will store the updated value, each time you click the button, put that array in this var, and use `final` to create the ui, try this:

```
let final = [];
$('.button1').click(function(){
    final = final.concat(obj);
    renderTweet(final); 
});
$('.button2').click(function(){
    final = final.concat(obj2);
    renderTweet(final); 
});
```

Check this for working example:

`jsbin`: https://jsbin.com/fofasuruno/edit?html,js,output

Comment: check the working code but i want to know, why you want to put the buttons in html ?? you can create a component that will contain the button and a child comp that will render the ui.

Comment: yeah it does seem to work but i believe it can cause complicated issues in big application....thanks though

Comment: i have created my app using pure jquery mess but since im transfering to react  gradually i would have to completely rewrite everything in order to create render whole ui  using react .